# Case/switch statement yields repeated results

Tags: java, switch-statement

So I have two case/switch statements, and for some reason the print statement that is being activated by the two variables is being activated twice. I read the code over and over again and couldn't find anything that would create a repeat of the print statements. The output is:

> The Dark Knight uses his cunning and strength of will to beat down the enemy once again.
>   Unfortunately, somebody brought Kryptonite :(
>   The Dark Knight uses his cunning and strength of will to beat down the enemy once again.
>   Unfortunately, somebody brought Kryptonite :(

Does anybody see the error? If so, thanks in advance for any answers; code below and faulty code is in quadruple quotes:

```
class Hero{
    String name;
    int intelligence;
    boolean parents;
    double strength;

    public static String fight(Hero hero1, Hero hero2){
    if(hero1.intelligence+hero1.strength>hero2.intelligence+hero2.strength)
        return(hero1.name+" is the winner");
    else{

        //If hero2 wins, initiate this code


    """"switch (hero2.name){
                                    //If the hero's name is ___ then print ____
                case "Batman":
                    System.out.println("The Dark Knight uses his cunning and strength of will to beat down the enemy once again.");
                    break;
                case "Superman":
                    System.out.println("Superman is literally invincible. The Son of Krypton wins again!");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                    }
            switch (hero1.name){

                case "Batman":
                    System.out.println("The Dark Knight trudges back to his cave");
                    break;
                case "Superman":
                    System.out.println("Unfortunately, somebody brought Kryptonite :(");
                default:
                    break;
                }""""
        return(hero2.name+" is the winner");

    }
}

class HeroMain{
    public void main(String[] args){
    Hero Superman = new Hero();
    Superman.name = "Superman";
    Superman.intelligence = 7;
    Superman.parents = false;

    Hero Batman = new Hero();
    Batman.name = "Batman";
    Batman.intelligence = 8;
    Batman.parents = false;

    Hero.fight(Superman, Batman);
    System.out.println(Hero.fight(Superman, Batman));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: show how you call the method.

Comment: `fight` is probably called twice.

Comment: exactly, SHOW YOUR CODE.

Comment: Really sorry about that, didn't even realize that my code was cut off.

Comment: @user2510460 YOu are calling `Hero.fight(Superman, Batman);` two times.

Comment: Using a debugger would have told you immediately what was happening.

Comment: Your main method is not declared `static`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Hero.fight(Superman, Batman);
System.out.println(Hero.fight(Superman, Batman));
```

You are calling the method twice, hence the double print.